# How to install vim-treesitter?

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-treesitter

I have installed neovim, it was cool so I installed vim-treesitter plugin.
I'm trying to use it but I get some error message.

I can't find solution about it.
Could you help me?

[image]

This is the error message I get:

[image]
and this is my init.vim file

I just copied the blog code, so I don't know well sorry ㅠㅠ

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). We will look at your problem but it would be helpful if instead of pasting a screen shot you could past the actual text as a quotation such that it can be reused by the one trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Probably: https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/2293#issuecomment-1094250553 :S

Answer (score 0):

Does the error message say `parser not available for language`?

If so, that suggests there's need to install/configure a parser.

What language/filetype needs a parser? What type of file are you editing in when this error appear? If this error appears when you're editing `init.vim` then maybe you need a parser for the `vim` filetype?

Also...

Images of code are difficult to read. Please copy and paste the code itself (not an image/screenshot of it).

Copy+pasting your error messages is important to do because in addition to pasting the errors into your question here when you're talking to us (this makes it easier for us to help you) you can also paste the errors into the search engine you use. For example, go to https://duckduckgo.com/ and search for:

```
neovim treesitter parser not available
```

or try this search query:

```
init.vim parser not available
```

or maybe this `parser not avaiable` error occurs when you're editing `.xyz` files? In which case search:

```
xyz treesitter parser neovim
```

Reading error messages isn't easy at first because it's hard to tell which part of it is most important... which part of the error message do you ignore, and which part of the error message do you use in your websearch/question?  In your case now it looks like `parser not available` is the most important part.

Comment: Additionally, if you're struggling to get treesitter working, you might want to check out https://github.com/LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide and https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch.

Comment: As much as I agree with all of the advice given here, I don't think this helpfully answers the OP's question (cf. https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: If you said this "doesn't comprehensively answer OP's question" I would completely agree. But it was much too verbose for a *comment* and it seems like the information would be helpful in this circumstance, particularly considering the sparseness of info in the question itself and the lack of other answers and the urgent need to get this neovim instance working properly :)

Comment: The sparseness of Q info is a reason to not answer, generally. And I don't know where you're drawing "urgent need" from. This answer basically explains to (1) google the problem and (2) read the error messages. Certainly short enough for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The input fields for `ensure_installed` is supposed to be a lua table. Something like `ensure_installed = {'lua', 'c'}` you are missing the curly braces in the Lua block for this attribute.